# Reapplying for an Internship I turned down few weeks ago

Tags: job-offer, internship, applications, rejection

I was looking for internships as a software engineer and got one but I was given 4 days to consider and reply to the offer. While during that time I was interviewing with some other company and that process was taking some time so I took the risk and turned down the first offer and now the other company had rejected me. Would it be unethical or very selfish to apply for the same company whose offer I turned down because I can see that the vacancy is still open?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's fine. But do not make the mistake of restarting the application process from scratch. Just email them, or call them. Contact the hiring manager directly if you can.

Comment: I don't see is as an issue but they could be having someone else in mind after your rejection with the company. Even though the job posting still says it's open, you unfortunately don't know if someone could be signing a job offer soon. I wish you good luck but I wouldn't be surprised if they chose the next person down the list. Next time, it is very much in your best interest to explain that you have another interview with another company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be unethical or very selfish to apply for the same company
>   whose offer I turned down because I can see that the vacancy is still
>   open?

No, it's perfectly ethical and not at all selfish to re-apply.

Don't wait though. The position likely won't remain open for long.

Answer (score 4):

Something similar happened to me, I called the company back and said there were some changes in my circumstances that now allowed me to be able to accept the offer and I ended up re-applying and getting a permanent job! You have nothing to lose